# Particle in an oscillating box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oscillators

This isn't a question for a class, it's just driven by curiosity.

I hope you like it.

Let's consider a particle in a box with infinite potential barriers, but now the walls can oscillate/move.

Does anyone ever heard of such a problem? I can't find any literature mentioning that.

However, my actual question is, how could an mathematical ansatz could look like?

Comment: I have heard of problems with *moving* barriers, the potential is time-dependent in such cases; so one must take care in solving the Schrodinger equation. What are these symmetries you speak of?

Comment: This paper looks at the case of uniformly moving walls: https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/34/8/3391/379873/Quantum-particle-in-a-box-with-moving-wallsQuantum?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus Sorry, in this case just one vibration mode exists. In two dimensions may exist further modes of vibration. With symmetrie I mean the symmetrie group of a vibrations like vibration modes of water. Was this understandable?

Comment: @FusRoDah Many thanks for the paper! This is exactly what I was looking for  I'm a chemist, therefore it could take a while until I understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

At least in classical electromagnetics, if you took a conducting box and vibrated one or more of its walls at 1/2 the frequency of one of its modes, you'd see energy building up in that mode as long as there was non-zero energy to start with.  I'm not sure if you could make one in the real world, though.

Google "[parametric oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_oscillator)"; if you find one of the microwave circuits that implement it, just replace their variable capacitors with my vibrating walls.

I'm not sure sure how directly the electromagnetic version of this translates to the quantum world, but my suspicion is that it's pretty direct -- I'd love to find out if I'm right or not.

Comment: Thank you for this hint 